# I want the integer that was asked to the user to go to the Cat class so it outputs the word "meow" until the counter is equal to the number

Tags: parameter-passing

This is the main method.
I want the integer that was asked to the user to go to the Cat class so it outputs the word "meow" until  the counter is equal to the number

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Runnable {
    **public static void main( String args[]) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        Cat cat1 = new Cat();
        
        System.out.print("Enter num :");
        int num.sound()=input.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("Calling method with no parameters");
        cat1.sound();
        System.out.println("Calling method with one parameter");
        cat1.sound();
    }
}
```

this is a Class called Cat

```
public class Cat {
    public void sound() {
       System.out.println("Meow"); 
    }
    public void sound( int num){
        int counter=0;
        for(int num1=counter; num1>=num; counter++) {
        System.out.println("Meow"); 
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things first:

- what you mean with the line:

  ```
    int num.sound()=input.nextInt();
  ```
- you not pass paramenters in

  ```
    System.out.println("Calling method with no parameters");
    cat1.sound();
    System.out.println("Calling method with one parameter");
    cat1.sound();
  ```

But the main flow is in the for loop that could be:

```
    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < num; num1++) 
    { ... }
```